# How do you run Ruby scripts?

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, ruby

I installed Ruby on Synaptic Package Manager but when I double click a `.rb` file it just opens using Leafpad instead of running. I can't find Ruby in the start menu and when I type Ruby in LXTerminal nothing happens.

I'm basically trying to figure out how to run https://dev.wikia.com/wiki/RubyWikiDownloader to make a copy of images in a folder as backup and transferring.

Comment: Did you install the `ruby` package? Doesn’t `ruby -- /path/to/script` work? What is its output? Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ruby installed you can try to open terminal in path you have `script.rb` and type:

```
   ruby your_program.rb
```

If you don't have ruby installed, you have to install it and retry.

Comment: How to you adjust the terminal to the path the script.rb is in?